# How to use sortChildren with createJS in Angular6 project?

Tags: angular, createjs, easeljs

In the CreateJS documentation (https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#method_sortChildren) they describe how to use the sortChildren function to sort a child list. I can't realy undrestand how to use it in my Angular6 project. Here is what I try to do but it doesn't work... Any idea ?
    `this.elementsLayer.sortChildren((a:any,b:any) =>
    {
    console.log(a.zIndex)
    if (a.zIndex < b.zIndex) return -1;
    if (a.zIndex > b.zIndex) return 1;
    return 0;
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to treat it as a higher-order function.

```
const zSort = (a, b) =>
    {
       console.log(a.zIndex)
       if (a.zIndex < b.zIndex) return -1;
       if (a.zIndex > b.zIndex) return 1;
       return 0;
    }

this.elementsLayer.sortChildren(zSort);
```